# What's the right way to commit git changes

Tags: git, github

I am exploring on GIT, but I am wondering what's the best way to keeping my code updated.

Should I always pull (keeping code updated) before I pushing my commit? Or if I keep commit my updates without pulling will it cause conflicts?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't push if you haven't pulled changes from your remote.
As with every source control, the best thing is to integrate often, and so I recommend dividing your work to small commits and then pushing them as often as you can.
A good flow IMO would be you committing a couple times an hour and every hour or so you'd pull changes from your team and push yours out.

Comment: You are right. We won't be able to push without first pulling it. Thank you!

Comment: Time is definitely not the right way to split up commits. You want logically coherent changes, with reasonable granularity.

Comment: please does anyone know the solemn difference between -a and -am when commiting because am really getting confused